# Powershell Invalid Spacename

Tags: windows, powershell, nfs

I'm trying to use nfs command on Powershell like "Get-NfsClientConfiguration" or "Get-NfsShare" but they aren't working.

I get an "invalid spacename" error.

I don't understand how to enable the module as it isn't checked when I type "get-WindowsFeatures".
I tried "Import-Module NFS" but it didn't change anything.
If you have some advice please.

Thank's

Comment: *I don't understand how to enable the module*... What module?

Comment: nfs module into powershell

Comment: If you run a cmdlet that's not installed, you get an error staying the command is not recognized. The fact you're not getting that error suggests the problem is *not* the cmdlet not being imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Install-WindowsFeature -Name NFS-Client